# Send JS-object from Java to JS-function as parameter for display Google map on JavaFX WebView

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx

I have desktop JavaFX application with WebView in which the Google Map is diplayed. 
I'm using JS for display map and set markers. Also I need take coordinates from database and set it on map.

HTML doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 900px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      var map;

      function setMarker(uluru) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }

      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        setMarker(uluru);
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And JavaFX contoller:

```
@FXML
WebView mapView;

public void initialize() {
    loadMap();
}

private void loadMap() {
    WebEngine mapEngine = mapView.getEngine();
    mapEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/html/index.html").toExternalForm());
    addMarker(mapEngine, 55.7453893, 37.8679919);
}

private void addMarker(WebEngine mapEngine, Double lat, Double lng) {

//    mapEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    //    if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
            String funcName = "setMarker";
            String params = "{lat: " + "'" + lat + "'" + ", lng: " + "'" + lng + "'" + "}";
            JSObject markFunc =  (JSObject) mapEngine.executeScript("this");
            markFunc.call(funcName, params);
    //    }
 //   });
}
```

I haven't any exceptions, but the second marker isn't added from Java code.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I recommend using primitive `double` instead of `Double` to prevent accidentally passing `null` and getting a NPE with a source that is hard to find... In this case you probably want to prevent passing something like `{lat: 'null'" + ", lng: 'null'}`. Furthermore a quick look at the [marker doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) reveals that you probably should remove the quotes or at least they are unnecessary...

Comment: Well something like `{lat: 'null', lng: 'null'}`... Forgot to remove one of the concatenations from the string in the previous comment.